# Grid View Row Command Event Post Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView control for uploading files I am uploading using RowCommand Event, My scenario is like this

1. User login and comes to the page and upload file
2. User login, enter some data and save it,post back will occur and data will be shown in Grid.

The Upload functionality is working fine in scenario 1, however its not working after scenario 2
This is my Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVUsers" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GVUsers_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GVUsers_RowCommand"
    OnRowDeleting="GVUsers_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="filedoc" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="filedoc" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnuploadfiles" runat="server" CommandName="fileupd" Text="Upload"
                                                            CssClas="uploadbtn" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GVUsers_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "fileupd")
    {
            //Upload File
    }
}
```

and this is how I am databinding

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //Assigning datasource and DataBinding
}
```

I also tried binding grid after the above condition,ie Binding Grid always,but no Luck

I tried assinging event handler from code behind,but same issue.
Also on Save Button I am doing this after saving

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Assigning datasource and DataBinding
}
```

as per I investigated the problem is in btnsave_click, but if I use only
`GVUsers.DataBind()` it will not show newly added records in the Grid.
I also have tried by disabling ViewState of the Grid.
I am databinding Grid with DataTable

How can I make RowCommand Working after post back or how can I re databind grid after post back?

Comment: if after using GVUsers.Databind() grid is displaying then it must be binding, so what new data is it not displaying, updated rows / cells  on the page ? or records from DB ?

Comment: if I use only GVUsers.DataBind(){Not re-assign datasource}, the grid is getting hide, but if I tell datasource too, then new record will appear in Grid

Comment: what is the relation between the uploaded file and user-entered data?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the user entered data via ajax call and refresh the page later.. it would help you avoid the post back call

Answer (score 0):

here is some change you need to

when your page load first time `bind gridview` on page load event

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //Assigning datasource and DataBinding
}
```

but when you call again `GVUsers.DataBind()` you need to re-assign datasource again with updated record

make sure your `grid view`  not in update panel beacause if you use update panel you can't get uploded file at server side

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, grid views's RowCommand event stops firing.

One solution that you can try is re-binding your grid every time your pages posts back i.e. move the grid binding logic out of the `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` condition.

You will see that the RowCommand event will now fire successfully. The problem with this solution is that you will lose any data captures within your grid e.g. data in text fields in rows. If you don't have this situation, then this solution is safe.